# What's the range on an Ender Chest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a limit to how far an ender chest will allow you to transport bulk items? If so how far is that limit?

Comment: Ender Chest does not "transport" items. It is simply present everywhere, so no, there are no areas where you cannot place an Ender Chest and open it.

Comment: Remember also that you cannot use hoppers with Ender Chests, if that is what you meant by "transport bulk items".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no limit.

From the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Chest):

> their contents are shared across all other Ender Chests placed
> anywhere, even in different dimensions.